# Как в wchar_t обработать управляющий символ?

Tags: c++, c

Я хочу считывать русские символы с терминала сразу в `wchar_t`, но как при этом можно обрабатывать, допустим, стрелку вверх?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19531248/arrow-keys-as-wide-chars

Comment: в с/с++ в принципе нет встроенной возможности обрабатывать управляющие символы, так что всё будет зависеть от ОС/библиотеки, которую ты для этого используешь...

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getch-getwch?view=msvc-160

Comment: В подобных вопросах полезно указать, в какой ОС вы программируете